# How to add custom attributes to the `DOCTYPE` tag with NextJS?

Tags: next.js

One of the requirements of a third party that I'm working with is that I need to add the following at the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

This is taken from [here](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

I've obviously looked at the NextJS [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) but I can't find a way to change this tag.

This is how it looks now with my custom `_document.ts`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta property . . .
    . . .
```

Is it possible to change it?

What about on page load? Doing `document.getElementsByTagName('!DOCTYPE html')` won't work obviously, so I'm not really sure what to do here.

Comment: Seems like it isn’t possible- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/10165

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just use dangerouslySetInnerHTML because it is impossible to insert <!DOCTYPE> and root tags into other tags. To be able to do such a thing is necessary to create an iframe tag and pass the HTML as a string in the srcDoc parameter. Just like that:

```
  const myhtml =
"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'><title>Document</title></head><body><h1>Teste</h1></body></html>"; 

return (
   <iframe srcDoc={myhtml}></iframe>
);
```